# Insert value where exists

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i have tried this code but i got error message near 'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ipk FROM graduation WHERE ipk > 2.0)' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO dimipk (range_ipk) VALUES ("ipk > 2.0") WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ipk FROM graduation WHERE ipk > 2.0)
```

i want to insert a name range (ipk > 2.0) if there is student in graduation which ipk > 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is to first make a select query that returns the data set you want to insert:

```
SELECT "ipk > 2.0" FROM graduation WHERE ipk > 2 LIMIT 1
```

And then use that select as the data set for INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO dimipk (range_ipk)
SELECT "ipk > 2.0" FROM graduation WHERE ipk > 2 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO dimipk(col_name)
SELECT * FROM("myval") AS tmp
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ipk FROM graduation WHERE ipk > 2.0)
LIMIT 1;
```